# Maui Can't open MSIX installer

Tags: .net, installation, publish, maui, msix

**The Error**

I published the default Maui Project but I can't open the installer msix file.
I always the error `The app was not started` with no further information why.

I can however install it using the powershell script which comes with the publishing.

Is there any way how I can fix this or just get a reasonable error message?

**More Info**

My dotnet version: `7.0.100`

My Visual Studio version: `17.5.0 Preview 1.0`

My Windows version: `Windows 11 22H2`

Comment: 1.Could you please try to install other `MSIX file`, will that throw an error?
2.Do you have any policy restrictions when Install MSIX file? 3. You can also open a thread as well in [the MSIX community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/msix/bd-p/MSIX-Discussions).

Comment: Sorry for the late answer (not much time currently). I'll take a look into this do you know an App or something where I could test a MSIX file?

Comment: You can create and test on your own.And for more details, you can go through the doc: [MSIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/overview)